# How to use NEOS without using Pyomo

Tags: optimization, modeling, modeling-languages, neos

I am new to modelling language and specifically NEOS server. I aim to solve MINLP using Baron, through the NEOS server. So, far I have been able to write model file, data file and command file as required by the NEOS server and get my results. However, I was wondering if there was a way to automate the process and call NEOS using Python without making the use of Pyomo since that would require change of modelling and I am certain that I don't have enough time to learn that and implement it correctly. I would be incredibly grateful if I could be guided to get around this.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. The neos server can be reached through some of the modelling language or programming languages like Python. Please, took a look at this [link](https://neos-guide.org/users-guide).